# Why am I getting multiple results for a command in Evennia?

Tags: python, mud

I'm building a text game in [Evennia](http://www.evennia.com). I've added a new typeclass called `Prop`. For now, it has a single command `wear`. I then created a couple of `Props` as prototypes and built them using `@spawn`. When I'm holding just one prop, its wear command works fine: `wear glove` returns "You're now wearing glove." But as soon as I have multiple props, all I get is the `.search()` disambiguation menu, and nothing I type seems to actually do the disambiguation.

I'm pretty sure that this has to do with cmdset merging, but that's as far as I got. What am I doing wrong?

mud/commands/prop_commands.py

```
"""
Prop commands


"""


from evennia import CmdSet
from command import Command




class CmdWear(Command):
    """
    Wear or remove a prop


    Usage:
      wear <prop>
      don <prop>
      doff <prop>


    Causes you to wear or remove the prop. {wdon{n and {wdoff{n will only put the prop on or off; {wwear{n form will toggle between worn and unworn.
    """


    key = "wear"
    aliases = ["don", "doff"]
    locks = "cmd:holds()"
    help_category = "Objects"


    def parse(self):
        """Trivial parser"""
        self.target = self.args.strip()


    def func(self):
        caller = self.caller
        if not self.target:
            caller.msg("Wear what?")
            return


        target = caller.search(self.target)
        if not target:
            caller.msg("Couldn't find any %s." % self.target)
            return


        # assumes it's a Prop typeclass, so assumes it has this attribute
        if not target.db.wearable:
            caller.msg("That doesn't make any sense.")
            return


        if self.cmdstring in ("don", "doff"):
            should_wear = True if self.cmdstring == "don" else False
        else:
            should_wear = not target.db.worn


        if target.db.worn ^ should_wear:
            target.db.worn = should_wear
            caller.msg("You're %s wearing %s." % (
                "now" if target.db.worn else "no longer",
                target))
        else:
            caller.msg("You're %s wearing %s." % (
                "already" if target.db.worn else "not",
                target))




class PropCmdSet(CmdSet):


    def at_cmdset_creation(self):
        self.add(CmdWear())
```

mud/typeclasses/props.py

```
"""
Props are items that can be held, worn, etc.


"""


from evennia import DefaultObject
from commands import prop_commands




class Prop(DefaultObject):
    """
    Props are items that can be held, worn, stood on, and more.
    """
    def at_object_creation(self):
        self.cmdset.add(prop_commands.PropCmdSet, permanent=True)


        self.db.wearable = True
        self.db.worn = False
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I wasn't getting a `.search` disambiguation. Instead, it was the command itself being disambiguated. The solution is to move the CmdSet to something other than the objects. Then there's only one Command no matter how many objects are in scope.